# Cant build app using npx grunt on Windows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

On Windows 8.1 installed Node.js 12.16.

First I run "npm install grunt" in a root directory of project.

Installation passed succesfully, however with the following warnings:

```
 npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@
 1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do m
 y best with it!
 npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
 npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.3.3: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffe
 escript" (no hyphen)
 npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
 npm WARN platform-web@0.0.1 No repository field.
 npm WARN platform-web@0.0.1 No license field.
 npm WARN The package time-grunt is included as both a dev and production depende
 ncy.
 npm WARN The package object-assign is included as both a dev and production depe
 ndency.

+ grunt@0.4.5
added 38 packages from 47 contributors and audited 54 packages in 3.026s
found 25 vulnerabilities (5 low, 6 moderate, 14 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Root directory containts grunt-folder (root_dir/grunt), in which Gruntfile.js and package.json files are located.

And this grunt-folder containts other grunt-folder (root_dir/grunt/grunt). This second grunt containts some js-files.

Then in "root_dir/grunt" I run "npx grunt". But the build aborted with the following log:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-includes" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-text-replace" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-cssmin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-file-creator" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-war" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "nexus-deployer" not found. Is it installed?

Warning: Task "clean:all" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

package.json is

```
{
   "name": "platform-web",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Platform",
   "devDependencies": {
   "archiver": "^0.12.0",
   "grunt": "^0.4.5",
   "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
   "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
   "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
   "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.12.3",
   "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
   "grunt-file-creator": "^0.1.3",
   "grunt-includes": "^0.5.1",
   "grunt-text-replace": "^0.4.0",
   "grunt-war": "^0.5.1",
   "nexus-deployer": "^0.1.8",
   "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
   "time-grunt": "^1.1.0"
 },
  "dependencies": {
   "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
   "object-assign": "^4.0.1"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s.: root-folder is:

[image: root]

Comment: Can you share your "package.json" file ? you have to install all "grunt-*" + "nexus-deployer" libs as dev dependancies.

Comment: Have you run an "npm install" before running "npm install grunt" ? in addition, run the grunt CLI with "npx grunt-cli" instead of "npx grunt"

Comment: I run "npm install" and "npx grunt-cli".  I still receive "Aborted...". But I have some progress: dist-folder appeared in grunt-folder.  The appearence of "dist" is a success-criteria of build-stage (based on working project-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Following is only needed for older versions of grunt. New one install the bunstubbs correctly so you can still install grunt via npm and not globally.

Install grunt-cli. This will correctly pick up whichever version of grunt the project is running and execute it.

```
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

In the package.json change `dev` script to

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "npx grunt-cli"
  }
```

then run

```
npm run start
```